# How to highlight weekend days in Emacs calendar?

Tags: emacs, calendar, elisp

I am using Emacs and open calendar, now i would like to highlight weekend days with a light background color, i tried to google but have no solid solutions. anyone can help on this? thanks a lot!

Sorry I can't post pictures yet, hope i have put the question clearly.

Comment: It looks like Drew Adams already wrote a solution for that issue -- have a look at:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/calendar+.el

Comment: Calendar+ has many great features, but mostly I won't use, that's why i choose a simpler solution. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have some code that does that.  You would need to change `font-lock-doc-string-face` to the face you want to use (or make a new one and configure it) if you don't like the one I used.

```
(defadvice calendar-generate-month
  (after highlight-weekend-days (month year indent) activate)
  "Highlight weekend days"
  (dotimes (i 31)
    (let ((date (list month (1+ i) year)))
      (if (or (= (calendar-day-of-week date) 0)
              (= (calendar-day-of-week date) 6))
          (calendar-mark-visible-date date 'font-lock-doc-string-face)))))
```

Comment: Very useful answer. How  to use a particular background/foreground color instead of `font-lock-doc-string-face`?